# How to send multiple variables to a php file with XMLHttpRequest using post method?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to send multiple variables to a php file within one XMLHttpReqyest , I can send 1 but I can't figure how to send more than 1.

for example if I have:

The HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="firstVal"/>
    <input type="text" id="secondVal"/>
    <input type="submit" id='send'/>
</form>
```

The JS:

```
var val1 = documennt.getElementById('firstVal');
var val2 = documennt.getElementById('secondVal');
var sendData = documennt.getElementById('send');

function checkData(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST" , 'file.php' , true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange  = function(){   
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}

sendData.addEventListener('click' , checkData);
```

How to send these variables to the file.php ?

Comment: You're code isn't sending anything

Comment: @Musa , I know it's not sending anything because I know how to send 1 variable not more